# How do I make a mouseover stick for a longer period of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, mouseover

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
$("#page-flip").mouseover(function() { 

    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
});
});
```

It works well, but the mouseover is a bit fidgety.  I'd like it to have it stick for a longer period of time, and to not flinch as much when it first triggers.  For instance if the user is moving his/her mouse quickly it should either fully release or not at all, instead of half-stepping.  Any ideas?

I think a a timeout is the way to go, but I've tried this and now the classes won't toggle.

```
function myMouseOver() 
{

    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");

}

$("#page-flip").mouseover(function() { 
          var t = setTimeout("myMouseOver()",1500);
});
```

Comment: Can you jsfiddle it? Not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here's a simple version of your code, it appears to work well, perhaps you can show us your HTML? http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/fWakf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delay javascript execution you can use **setTimeout** or **setInterval**

try this:

```
function myMouseOver()
{
    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
}


$("#page-flip").mouseover(function() { 
  var t = setTimeout("myMouseOver()",1500);
});
```

I've made a jsFiddle for you, tell me if this is what you had in mind : 
http://jsfiddle.net/alexpeta/fWakf/5/

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but now the classes aren't toggling when I mouseover #page-flip.

Comment: try using jQyery.hover() not just mouseover .http://api.jquery.com/hover/. I would also have a global variable involved that is incremented when an animation is running and 0 when no animation is running and when another animation  has to start to check that variable. this wouould prevent chaining hoverin/hover out if the user is waving the mouse on and off

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `mouseenter` event instead of the `mouseover` event? It's designed to only trigger when the cursor enters the region of an element, not for instance when you `mouseover` a sub element and then `mouseout` of that sub element:

```
$(function() {

    $("#page-flip").mouseenter(function() { 

        $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
        $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
        $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on js.fiddle. This function will emulate mouseover with consistent behaviour.

```
$(function() {
$("#page-flip").mouseenter(function() { 

    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
})
$("#page-flip").mouseleave(function() { 

    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html), which debounces mouse hover events for you.

```
$(selector).hoverIntent(hoverCallback, leaveCallback);
```